# How to use custom :sitemap-function with org-publish?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I have this component in org-publish list :

```
("presentations"
:base-directory "~/presentations/org/"
:base-extension "org"
:publishing-directory "~/presentations/"
:publishing-function org-reveal-publish-to-reveal
:auto-sitemap t
:sitemap-filename "index.html"
:sitemap-function org-publish-org-sitemap)
```

How can I avoid `:publishing-function org-reveal-publish-to-reveal`
from adding `reveal.js` styles to sitemap file. I just want to have
all the files listed in index.

Edit:
I'm doing this to regenerate index file with org-html-publish-to-html.

```
("presentations-index"
         :base-directory "~/presentations/org/"
         :base-extension nil
         :exclude ".*"
         :include ["index.org"]
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :publishing-directory "~/presentations/"
         :auto-sitemap nil)
("presentations"
         :base-directory "~/presentations/org/"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/presentations/"
         :publishing-function org-reveal-publish-to-reveal
         :auto-sitemap t
         :sitemap-title "[ Presentations ]"
         :sitemap-filename "index.org"
         :exclude "index.org"
         )
("present" :components ("presentations" "presentations-index"))
```